# Mongoose - save after lean

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm fetching an object from mongo using mongoose but i want to use lean as there are attributes that aren't in mongoose model (strict:false)
After modifying that object i can't save it back

```
let order = await Order.findOne({_id: req.body.id}).populate({path: 'o_s', match: {removed: false}}).lean()


order.save() //not working as it's not mongoose model any more
Order.update({_id:order._id},{order}).exec(function(){
                                    return res.json({status: true, message: 'Order Updated', order: order});
                                }) //not giving error but not updating too
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: `.lean()` and `{ strict: false }` where the latter is set on the schema are **two completely different things**. The `strict` allows "attributes not in the model" but the basic returned object is **still a mongoose document** and has a `.save()` method. The moment you use `lean()`, you *throw all of that away* and simply get a "plain JavaScript Object". Therefore make it `{ strict: false }` and **DON'T** use `lean()` here, in the context of what you are actually expecting to happen.

Comment: yes but i can't modify attributes that aren't in the model without lean  @NeilLunn

Comment: You **CANNOT HAVE BOTH** is the only subtle way to put that. If you want to modify away from the schema, then you use `lean()`. If you want to have the schema methods available, then you don't. There is no middle ground. As long as your "modification" does not actually break the schema rules ( or you actually had `{ strict: false }` assigned ) then what you *"can"* do it feed the plain object back into a model constructor. As in `let newOrder = new Order(order)`. That's allowed, but you can't have both without explicitly doing something like that.

Comment: @NeilLunn but using new Oder will generate a new ObjectID for it, right ?

Comment: WRONG. If you have an `_id` field present in the document data you supply ( and since you are not suppressing it, then you will ) then **that value** is what will be used. What's more is Mongoose will "autocast" the "string" value into an `ObjectId` value for you.

Comment: @NeilLunn ok,thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the doc you retrieved from the db, you have to remove the _id property.

Consider this contrived example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
const conn = mongoose.connection;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
  name: String
});

schema.set('strict', false);

const Test = mongoose.model('test', schema);

const test = new Test({
  name: 'Henry',
  nick: 'Billy'
});

async function run() {
  await conn.dropDatabase();
  await test.save();
  let doc = await Test.findOne({}).lean();
  const id = doc._id;
  delete doc._id;
  doc.name = 'Billy';
  doc.nick = 'The Kid';
  await Test.update({ _id: id }, doc);
  let updated = await Test.findOne({});
  console.log(updated);
  return conn.close();
}

run();
```

**output:**

```
{ _id: 5ad34679bc95f172c26f3382,
  name: 'Billy',
  nick: 'The Kid',
  __v: 0 }
```

note that you lose auto versioning in this scenario, if this is important to you, you'll need to manually increment the version property.

Comment: I tried this with and without deleting the __v property of the doc. In both scenarios mongoose does not increment the version as I expected it to. I also instinctively put { strict: false } in the update call, but this was not needed so I removed it.

Answer (score -1):

i suggest to doesn't use lean() because it has some performance isues that i realized.
otherwise you can use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(order)) and for some reasean it's a better approach. especially wen you want to iterate over the result ( in my case it was two times faster for iteration).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32653975)